# Why is vertical scrolling of XML files in Visual Studio 2010 so slow?

Tags: xml, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Has anyone had this problem?  My projects tend to have some long XML files and I need to scroll all the time.  Why is scrolling of XML files so slow?!  It's really annoying!  It was definitely fine when I was using VS 2005.  Do you know why it is so slow and how I can fix it?

Comment: Do other very large files scroll slowly, or is it just XML?

Comment: No the other files scroll fine.  All my XML files scroll slow, even the ones that are not very long.  Thanks

Comment: Did you try disabling syntax highlighting or changing your font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever since I upgraded to a more powerful machine I don't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the following options in Text Editor => XML => Miscellaneous:

- Automatically download DTDs ans schemas
- Enter outlining mode when file open